# GWT Websockets Technology

Tags: gwt, websocket

I'm looking for a way to use websockets in GWT. There are some APIs but i heard that they don't work in developement mode. Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

I use [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) and it works fine.
You will find a chat for example in GWT.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are talking about [Comet](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/wiki/GettingStarted) and [Gwt-Ws.](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-ws/)

To make them work you have to configure your [Jetty server](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-jetty/)  I mean to use [JettyLauncher](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-jetty/).

And the above frameworks supports in Webkit browsers  like `Chrome` , `Safari`.

Comment: Do these APIs really work? Do you use them? Because the last changes have been a long time ago.

Comment: I remember that in my old project we used comet,And tested in google chrome.And that too for only server push with time span 1min.Sorry,Can''t provide any code snippet because of i'm out of that project.

Comment: ok, thank you. But you can not guarantee that comet also works with the newest gwt version?

Comment: Yes.Why i am sure comet frame work it self have CometListener,Comet client etc..a less gwt interation(max on data received) will needed.

Comment: i can't believe that there is no websockets solution for GWT 2.5

Comment: OOPs my comment may goes into a wrong way i think. Didn't agree with comet solution :)  ??

Comment: My application sends lots of server events in a sec, so comet is with polling not the best solution

Comment: gwteventservice also uses polling

Comment: And a complete example with code here https://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/wiki/CodeExamples  .Good luck :)

Comment: by seeing the comment in the first link i have shared "These advantages are not guaranteed for all cases and could also be disadvantages in some special cases compared with polling or other technologies" ..it wont use pooling .Do you agree ??

Comment: I agree. It uses Long polling and streaming as you can see in the manual. The second technology is a little dirty, but it seems to be the best for my project. But websockets would be quite better...

Comment: Now i agreed with you. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

### This can be achieved with JSNI and stomp over sockjs

1. ClientBundle with TextResource for this two javaScript.files
2. Inject this TextResources as Script(don't miss setRemoveTag(false) as this is FromString)

   ```
   ScriptInjector.fromString(myRes.sockJs().getText()).setRemoveTag(false).inject();
   ```
3. And establish a connection in JSNI

   ```
   var socket = new SockJs('myPath');
   var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
   var connect_callback = function() {.....}
   stompClient.connect({}, connect_callback)
   ```

You are able to return this stompClient as JavaScriptObject and later in jsni methods subscribe or send messages, or take a look at GWT JSNI Overlay functionality.